# Can't figure why for-loop runs 5 times and not 4 times

Tags: c++

I'm having hard times figuring out why this for-loop runs 5 times and not 4 times as I "calculated" when reading the code.

```
float a;
int i = 0;
for(a = 0.01; a < 100; a *= 10)
    i++;
cout << i << endl;
```

My thoughts:
After the 4th run the value of `a` is `100`, with that the for loop should 'break'
as 100 is **not** smaller then 100 (`a < 100`), giving the output of `cout << i` should be then `4`.

However the loop runs 5 times and not 4 times, and that doesn't makes sense for me because `100 < 100` (`a < 100`) passes and after the 5th run `a` is equal to 1000 and not 100.

Comment: Read up on "what every scientist should know about floating point". But essentially, a floating point number is represented as a fraction scaled by a power of the base (numeral system radix). That means that only a limited set of values is representable. For example, on almost all modern computers `0.01` is not exactly representable as a floating point value, because they use base 2.

Comment: When you have problems like this, it helps to print the index variable (a) and see what happens. Like other said, it is probably an issue with the floating point precision.

Comment: Add `cout << a << endl;` into the loop and you will see your trouble.

Comment: I did, that's why I was wondering that `a` is 1000 and not 100.

Comment: @CriticalException How do you know `a` is 1000 and not just _near_ 1000.? Print with higher precision - at least 20 decimal digits.

Comment: It's the first time i see float as a loop variable

Comment: @CriticalException -- It is worse than you believe.   In the loop, you're starting off with an inexact number.  `a = 0.01` is not exact, since `0.01` cannot be represented exactly in binary.  So on the first iteration you're multiplying 10 by an inexact `0.01`, creating more precision issues on each iteration.  If you want to loop 4 times, use integer loop counters to represent "4 times", not floating point.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did this for testing purpose to  learn some C++ as I'm beginner. But yes you're right :), I'm not gonna use float for loops.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.01 * 10^4` is 100 however due to floating point precision you most likely end up with `99.999324234` or something similar. This is due to the conversion from binary numbers to decimals.

Hope this explanation helps.